# Bootstrap Succes Message disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Form and there I have an ajax code to give the Data to the .php script.

The Problem is, my ajax Code only shows the Success Message for 1 second and disappear after that..
Here the code:

```
 $( '#frmContact').submit( function() {
      var formcheck = true
      var name =$( '#name' );

     if(name.val() == '')
     {

         $( '#name-group-name' ).addClass( 'has-error' );
         $('#name-group-name').append('<div class="help-block">' + 'error' + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
            return false;

     }
     if(formcheck) {

      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php", // 
                data: $('frmContact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert' );
                    $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert-success' );
                    $( '#message').html( msg );


                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    return false
                }
            });

    }


 } );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your custom time by following way:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(".alert-success").addClass('hide'); }, 5000);
```

Comment: @Kramilu just after  $( '#message').html( msg );

Comment: Hm same ...Here the Full Code.. I Have a bigge rproblem maybe?
http://codebin.org/view/c67a532d

Comment: @Kramilu Add it after  $( '#message').html( msg ); .

Comment: @Kramilu you have also need to add following code before your form :                                                                                                          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></div>

Comment: Okay, I did this but now i have a green box .. 
Without anything in it.

Comment: you have to put your suucess msg inside this green box.